# Convert a long list to binary dataframe

Tags: r

The input dataframe has a long format and contains info for one user into more than one rows.

Example

```
d_long <- data.frame( nameid = c("sally","sally","sally","Robert","annie","annie"), value = c("product1","ra","ent","ra","ra","product1"))
```

> ```
> nameid    value
> 1  sally product1
> 2  sally       ra
> 3  sally      ent
> 4 Robert       ra
> 5  annie       ra
> 6  annie product1
> ```

How could it be possible to transform it to a binary dataframe like this:

```
d_exist <- data.frame(nameid = c("sally","Robert","annie"), product1 = c(1,0,1), ra = c(1,1,1), ent = c(1,0,0))
```

> ```
>  nameid product1 ra ent
> 1  sally        1  1   1
> 2 Robert        0  1   0
> 3  annie        1  1   0
> ```

Comment: Try with `table` `table(d_long)` or `reshape2:: dcast(d_long, nameid ~ value, length)` or `library(tidyverse);d_long %>% mutate(n = 1) %>% spread(value, n, fill = 0)`

Comment: @akrun Sorry. I didn't notice your comment before answering. I think your comments are good enough for answer of this question.

Comment: @akrun Thanks much. I should have been watchful before adding answer. I must mentioned you in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@akrun has provided quite few good options for this question but one of those option can be to use `tidyr::spread` to convert in wide-format. Though OP has not clearly mentioned if there can be multiple occurrence of a `nameid` and `value` but it would be good to include `count` for that group. The solution will be as:

```
library(tidyverse)

d_long %>% group_by(nameid, value) %>%
  mutate(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(value, count, fill = 0) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#   nameid ent product1 ra
# 1  annie   0        1  1
# 2 Robert   0        0  1
# 3  sally   1        1  1
```